# How to execute a script before page loaded with Selenium and ChromeDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to execute scripts before page loaded by ChromeDriver. Could the selenium have any function like the Page.onInitialized of PhantomJS?

Comment: I dunno! have you checked the specs nad APIs?

Comment: Use can use static block

Comment: @JackFlamp I check all documentation of selenium but I can find a little about that.

Comment: @KuldeepYadav The static block is unavailable in selenium